# ¿Cómo pasar valores entre Backbone Views en diferentes paginas?

Tags: javascript, html, vistas, backbone

Tengo un *View* con [backbone](/questions/tagged/backbone) que muestra un listado de items y tengo otro *View* que utilizo para editar cada item.

El problema consiste en que cada *View* se encuentra en un HTML diferente y cuando trato de editar no puedo pasar los valores desde el *View* de listado hacia el *View* de edición porque se hace *postback* y los valores se pierden.

¿Alguien conoce alguna forma de pasar los valores de un *View* a otro (entre páginas) sin tener que hacer un *SPA*?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta lo siento. Pero yo entre vistas independientes no les paso los datos, si no solo las claves primarias en la url, para luego solicitárselos al servidor y editar. En caso de que tenga ya los datos necesarios, la vista que crea la vista de edición y la que crea la vista de lista deberían tener acceso a dicho modelo y la que inicializa la de edición le pasaría solo los datos del item seleccionado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno hasta el momento la única opción que encontré fue almacenar en el `SessionStorage` o pasar por URL los valores necesarios para volver a recuperar los datos después del `postback`.

Si alguien tiene una mejor opción favor comentar.

Comment: Hola, creo que la solución  que propones es la adecuada puesto que no quieres hacer una SPA. Otra opción sería guardar los datos persistentes en una Cookie aunque personalmente prefiero cualquiera de las dos que has propuesto tu. Saludos